# SQL Updating Values of Column for Each Unique Value in Separate Column (without a loop)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, common-table-expression

I'm currently writing a query that is grabbing data from a table and I want to update one of the columns in that table.  The update needs to be based off the distinct values from one column.  For example:

| Type | ID |
| --- | --- |
| x | ID1 |
| x | ID1 |
| y | ID2 |
| y | ID2 |
| z | ID3 |
| z | ID3 |

The catch here is that I can't use a loop to do it.

The table has a lot more columns but I'm only sorting it by "Type" and then updating that table and assigning a unique ID based off its "Type"

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dense_rank() for this:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable(type VARCHAR(10), id VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES
  ('x', NULL), ('x', NULL),
  ('y', NULL), ('y', NULL),
  ('z', NULL), ('z', NULL);

UPDATE myTable
  JOIN (SELECT type, dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY type) AS id FROM myTable) ids 
    ON myTable.type = ids.type
   SET myTable.id = concat('ID', ids.id);
```

results in

| type | id |
| --- | --- |
| x | ID1 |
| x | ID1 |
| y | ID2 |
| y | ID2 |
| z | ID3 |
| z | ID3 |

More information about dense_rank() can be found in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_dense-rank)

Comment: Thank you! I just found this function as you answered and was able to make it work!

Comment: Very good, thanks for your feedback though.

Comment: do you know how you might incorporate the NEWID() function into this?  i.e, lets say I wanted to change the ID to be the result of NEWID() as opposed to just concatenating ID w/ the dense_rank

Comment: MySQL has no NEWID() function. You could use UUID(), e. g. `UPDATE myTable JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT type, uuid() as id from (SELECT DISTINCT type FROM myTable) dt) ids ON myTable.type = ids.type SET myTable.id = ids.id;`